# Connection Time Out error while accessing Google Play Store in Samsung I9070 Galaxy S advance

Tags: google-play-store, 2.3-gingerbread, connection-issues

I have bought a Samsung I9070 Galaxy S advance. Whenever I enter Play Store (Google Play Store Version 3.4.7), it displays waiting sign and then Connection Time Out Error is shown. I use mobile data connection to access the network. Please help me to solve this asap

Phone Details:

> Device: Samsung Galaxy S Advance
>     Android Version: 2.3.6
>     Baseband version: I9070DDLI1
>     Kernel version: 2.6.35.7-1194396  dpi@DELL163#2  SMP PREEMPT Thu Sep 13 22:11:28 KST 2012
>     Build Number: Gingerbread.DDLI1

Comment: Can you browse to websites via the browser successfully?  Can you browse secure (`https`) sites via the browser?  Can you use other Google account applications (like GMail)?

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem. Just bought a new Galaxy S Advance, 2.3. I'm not able to download any app. I tried to clean the cache and fix the time, doing a factory reset but nothing helped. I think the cause is that my same gmail is linked with my old Android phone as well as this new one. Now I'm going to upgrade to ICS version soon, hope that will help me. Good Luck

Comment: Same issue on a Colours ShineII.

Comment: I have the same issue. I have try everything in this post but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after upgrading my Android version. I fixed it by clearing the Google Play store cache and data. Go to `Menu Settings > Applications > Google Play Store` and click  the `Clear cache` button and `Clear data` button.

Comment: That didn't work for me on a Colours Shine II.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure date and time are correct.

That will more than likely fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings-> mobile network -> access point name
Try the one without the proxy.

It may resolve the issue.